# Method of Moments Estimator and its bias

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, estimation

Let $X_1,.....,X_n$ be a random sample from population with density

$$f(x) =\frac{\beta}{x^{\beta+1}} \qquad x \geq 1$$

Use the method of moments to find an estimator for the parameter beta. Upon solving I found that

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\overline{X}}{\overline{X}-1}$$

However I am not sure how to show that the estimator is biased. Can I get some help with that?

Comment: You should state the support for $f(x)$, presumably here $[1,\infty)$.  It might be better to write your answer as $\hat \beta = \dfrac{\bar X}{\bar X - 1}$.  To find the bias, calculate $\mathbb E[\hat \beta]-\beta$ though this may not be easy for $n>1$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Henry, we write
$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\overline{X}}{\overline{X}-1}$$
A quick computation yields that $E(X) = \frac{\beta}{\beta-1}$, which you already probably obtained in computing your method of moments estimator. Notice that the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x-1}$ is strictly convex on $[1, \infty )$, so Jensen's inequality gives us that:
$$E(\hat{\beta}) = E \left( \frac{\overline{X}}{\overline{X}-1} \right) > \frac{E(\overline{X})}{E(\overline{X}) -1 } = \frac{\beta/(\beta-1)}{\beta/(\beta-1)-1} = \beta$$

showing that the estimator is biased.